# Получение и изменение поля данных mysql одним запросом

Tags: mysqli, php

Приветствую.

Для изменения числового поля сначала запрашиваю данные этого поля, после получения значения делают второй запрос - изменяю, после уменьшения поля на 1.
Полагаю можно оптимизировать этот процесс и сделать один запрос, который не будет запрашивать, а потом обновлять, а сразу уменьшит значение на единицу, каким бы оно не было (положительным или отрицательным).

Поизучал информацию о составных запросах, но конкретное решение в голову пока не пришло.
Будьте добры, направьте на путь истинный? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уменьшать значение в поле можно так:

```
UPDATE table SET number = number - 1 WHERE id = 5;
```

Только тут надо иметь в виду, если поле объявлено как UNSIGNED, то если в number будет 0, то будет ошибка. В этом случае можно воспользоваться таким запросом:

```
UPDATE table set number = IF(number > 0, number - 1, 0) WHERE id = 5;
```

Comment: UPDATE table SET number = '(number) - 1' WHERE id = 5;

Вот так писал, чисто интуитивно - не работало, оказалось думал в правильном направлении, нужно лишь было ещё один шажок сделать к самопознанию:)
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET column = column - 1;
```

Comment: И вам спасибо:)